# Python loop won't exit properly

Tags: python

```
    if PathDriver is False:
        print('Chromedriver file is missing..')
        with open(FileName, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in chromedriver.iter_content(chunk_size=2561100122314):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
                    print('Downloading...')
                    print('Extracting...')
                    sleep(5)
        with zipfile.ZipFile('chromedriver_win32.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extract('chromedriver.exe')
            sleep(1)
            print('Done. Restart software Please.')
            print('Press CNTRL + C to exit.')
        for remaining in range(10, 0, -1):
            sys.stdout.write("\r")
            sys.stdout.write("{:2d} Program will exit in.".format(remaining))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
            exit(0)
```

That's the code above, I'm trying to get it to download chromedriver extract it then after that count down from 10 and exit.
what actually happens is it prints out till "extracting" and then print the start of the count down and returns back to the start of the code where it downloads chromedriver.

I decided to do it like this because without the exit and the timer if I run the code and chromedriver is missing it was supposed to download it and then continue to the next section where it uses chromedriver however it would do the same thing where it would just infintly loop the download.

if someone has an idea to fix any of these issues it would help a lot.

Comment: I dont see a break clause? Wdym exit properly? The loop will be done once all the chunks have been interated over.

Comment: One potential bug could be `PathDriver` is never made True, as per this code!

Comment: What do you expect this `exit(0)` in a for loop to do?

Comment: 1. I tried putting in a break at the end of the loop it stops at the start of timer same with exit

Comment: 2. I didn't include the line but right after this there is a like for PathDriver = True

Comment: 3. After the time ends I want it to close the script to force the user to restart - either that or remove the whole timer lines and just once its done extracting the zip move on to the next section with Pathdriver = True. but in that case it just infinity loops the downloading.. extracting..